# The ReadLine() method doesn't accept the line. Any solutions?

Tags: c#, console.readline

**The ReadLine() method doesn't accept the string and the program is executed without reading the string as shown in the output.**

```
using System;

namespace ReadReadLineMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            //using read method
            Console.WriteLine("Write a character: ");
            char a=(char)Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            //using readline method
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a line: ");
            string s=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Console input is line-buffered, you have to press the Enter key to submit the input.  Consider ReadKey() instead.

Comment: So your suggestion is like `string s=Console.ReadKey()`instead of `string s=Console.ReadLine()`

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is caused by the Read call that reads only one single character from the standard input stream but, when you type the letter 'a' followed by the Enter key, you are inserting in the input 3 characters: the letter 'a', the carriage return and the line feed. These two last chars are not removed from the input stream by Read and are still there when you call ReadLine. Of course this cause ReadLine to exit immediately without anything to return.

You could change the call to Read to another ReadLine to remove also the CR/LF inserted by the enter key and, if you want a single char, you can extract it from the returned string

```
Console.WriteLine("Write a character: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
// Decide what default you want
char a = input.Length > 0 ? input[0] : ' ';
Console.WriteLine(a);
```